# how to mark more hp in a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use the command

```
execute as @a[scores={health=<number>}] at @s run tp <coordinates>
```

with multiple lives? For example, in the command

```
execute as @a[scores={health=1}] at @s run tp 0 10 0
```

do not teleport only when it has 1 hp but teleport when it has less than 10 or 4 to 10 hp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the scoreboard objective for health set up, you can check for values in a range using `min..max`, for example, if you want to execute at all players with less than 10 (9 or less), you would use `@a[scores={health=..9}]` as the selector.

To disable someone from jumping, you can give them jump boost 128 with `/effect give Player jump_boost 10 127`

Comment: Note that if a `min` or `max` is omitted, it is assumed to be it's corresponding infinity, negative infinity for `min` and `positive` infinity for max. So `..9` means anything (negative infinity) up to 9.

Comment: @Penguin That's true but if the health objective corresponds to player health you can safely assume it won't go below zero.

Comment: ik i was just adding what omitting the number meant, because u never specified

Comment: and it is working with pozition too?